# Are the list of products being purchased required for the Google Analytics enhanced eCommerce checkout step?

Tags: google, google-analytics, ecommerce, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I want to push checkout step data dynamically to GA Enhanced Ecommerce (after each AJAX step progression), but I don't currently have access to the array of products in the cart. I have the step push working fine, but am wondering if I actually need the product data for each step push? The products are already being pushed once (at the cart then success states), so before I try to integrate them I thought I'd check first.

E.g instead of this below, can I just push the event with actionField etc:

```
dataLayer.push({  
    "event":"checkout",
    "ecommerce":{  
    "checkout":{  
        "actionField":{  
            "step":""
        },
        "products":[  
            {  
                "sku":"99999",
                "name":"Bue Jacket",
                "price":"99.0000",
                "priceexcludingtax":"79.20",
                "tax":"19.80",
                "taxrate":20,
                "type":"configurable",
                "category":"1841",
                "quantity":1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```